# Multiple regex replace together in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get as input to a function in scala a dataframe that has a column named **vin**.
The column has values in the below format

```
1. UJ123QR8467
2. 0UJ123QR846
3. /UJ123QR8467
4. -UJ123QR8467
```

and so on.

The requirement is to clean the column vin based on the following rules.

```
1. replace **"/_-** as ""
2. replace first 0 as ""
3. if the value is more than 10 characters then make the value as NULL.
```

I would like to know is there any simplified way to achieve the above.
I can only think of doing multiple .withcolumn during regex replace every time.

Comment: I upvoted because "I can only think of doing multiple withcolumn" and the answer suggests doing multiple withcolumn.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine all `Regex` related changes in a single transformation and the `length` condition in another, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  "UJ123QR8467", "0UJ123QR846", "/UJ123QR8467",
  "-UJ123QR8467", "UJ0123QR84", "UJ123-QR_846"
).toDF("vin")

df.
  withColumn("vin2", regexp_replace($"vin", "^[0]|[/_-]", "")).
  withColumn("vin2", when(length($"vin2") <= 10, $"vin2")).
  show
// +------------+----------+
// |         vin|      vin2|
// +------------+----------+
// | UJ123QR8467|      null|
// | 00UJ123QR84|0UJ123QR84|
// |/UJ123QR8467|      null|
// |-UJ123QR8467|      null|
// |  UJ0123QR84|UJ0123QR84|
// |UJ123-QR_846|UJ123QR846|
// +------------+----------+
```

Note that I've slightly expanded the sample dataset to cover cases such as non-leading `0`, `[/_-]`.